# Validating a cloned/repeatable input using PHP and/or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, validation, clone

I'm trying to create a repeatable field (an upload image input with image preview) in PHP using `jQuery.clone()`. Everything works fine, except the return of the clone data.

In my PHP file, I have:

```
$i = 0;
$valid_input['image'] = $input['image'][$i];
```

then

```
return $valid_input;
```

used in an image upload input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="image" name="image[image]['.$i.']" value="'.$theme_options['image'].'" />
    <input type="button"  class="upload-button button" value="'. __( 'Upload Image', 'theme' ).'" />
```

the value of $i is set to 0 and counted with jQuery clone.

The problem is that the cloned fields disappear after submitting.
The original field "image['image'][0]" is saved and returns as valid, but the others (image['image'][1], [2], [3]...) don't validate!

If I change the value of `$i` like this:

```
$i = 1;
$valid_input['image'] = $input['image'][$i];
```

then the original input don't submit, only the clone, because the original is [0] and the clone is [1], but after submitting the clone returns as [0].

I tried things like:

```
$i = 0;
$valid_input['image'] = $input['image'][$i];
$i++; //-- I know, I'm stupid...this will not count the input!
```

Please, can somebody help me with this?
How can I be able to validate the cloned fields?
My Google searches are all marked as visited and I swear that I did not find anything that could solve this!
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count( $input["image"] ); $i++) {
   echo $input["image"][$i];
}
```

or did i get you wrong

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
Your code seems to work, when I submit the form I noticed that each field has its own data stored, independently, but the cloned field does not return on the screen, it disappears but without overriding the previous field. when I clone again it's possible to see the values that I typed on the description field(in the 'autocomplete' feature of the inputs), of the cloned field so, it's been stored on database as an independent field!
I hope you got what I mean! =X

Answer (score 0):

please try with this

using the input name as image[] so you will get the value of image as an simple array by using the foreach you can do you validation.

i.e.,

```
$arrValue = $_POST['image'];

foreach ($arrValue as $key=>$value) {
//do the operations here

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I tried  your code, it validates, but when I submit the cloned field it's overriding the previous input and the cloned field disappears!